# Traefik on Docker stripprefix / to current directory

Tags: windows, docker

I am trying to setup a simple stripprefix middleware using Docker Desktop with unix containers and i get a very wiered behavior.

The static traefik-config comes from environment-variables:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --rm \
-a STDOUT \
--name traefik \
--network elastic \
-e TRAEFIK_ACCESSLOG=false \
-e TRAEFIK_API_INSECURE=true \
-e TRAEFIK_PROVIDERS_DOCKER_ENDPOINT="tcp://docker.for.win.localhost:2375" \
-e TRAEFIK_PROVIDERS_DOCKER_NETWORK="elastic" \
-e TRAEFIK_PROVIDERS_DOCKER_SWARMMODE=false \
-e TRAEFIK_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG \
-v c:/dev/repos/docker/dockerfiles/traefik/ssl/localhost.crt:/ssl/traefik-server.crt \
-v c:/dev/repos/docker/dockerfiles/traefik/ssl/localhost.key:/ssl/traefik-server.key \
${custom_image}
```

I start a service using a middleware defined with labels like this:

```
  -l traefik.http.routers.test.middlewares=test \
    -l traefik.http.middlewares.test.stripprefix.prefixes=/test/my-service \
    -l traefik.http.middlewares.test.stripprefix.forceslash=false
```

As a result i would expect a stripprefix-middleware with "/test/my-service"  appear in traefik dashboard.
Instead

A stripprefix-middleware with "C:/dev/tools/git/" appears in the treafik dashboard. Appearently traefik somehow resolves the first "/" into the directory-path.

I start the whole thing using Git-Bash.

If anyone encountered something like this, i would really appreciate some pointers...

P.S.: i also tried all kinds of escaping and quoting i could think of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe to prevent others wasting as much time....

... Turns out that git-bash for windows does some crazy stuff before handing the commands to docker.
Executing the exact same config using IntelliJ (docker-integration) or powershell does not replace the leading "/" with a windows path.